# Export Bezier curve animation

Tags: animation, scripting, bezier-curves

I am trying to export a Bezier curve I have animated.
This is what I have so far:

```
def getBezierPathNode(doc, frames, obj):
    node = doc.createElement("vertices")    

    for i in range(len(bpy.data.objects[obj].data.splines[0].bezier_points)):
        vertex = doc.createElement("vertex")
        vertex.setAttribute("id", str(i+1))
        attenuation = doc.createElement("attenuation")
        attenuation.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(str(0.5)))
        vertex.appendChild(attenuation)

        for fn, f in enumerate(frames):
            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
            o = bpy.data.objects[obj]
            points = o.data.splines[0].bezier_points
            point = points[i]
            print((f,point.co))
            frame = doc.createElement("frame")
            frame.setAttribute("num", str(fn))
            setPoint(o, frame, "", point.co)
            setPoint(o, frame, "a", point.handle_right)
            if i < len(points)-1:
                setPoint(o, frame, "b", points[i+1].handle_left)
            else:
                setPoint(o, frame, "b", point.co)
            vertex.appendChild(frame)

            node.appendChild(vertex)

    node.setAttribute("num", str(len(points)))
    node.setAttribute("frames", str(len(frames)))
    return node

def getFrames():
    frames = []

    for action in bpy.data.actions:
        for fcurve in action.fcurves:
            for k in fcurve.keyframe_points:
                fr = k.co[0]
                frames.append(fr)

    frames = list(set(frames))
    frames.sort()
    return frames

frames = getFrames()
doc = Document()
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == 'CURVE':
        node.appendChild(getBezierPathNode(doc, frames, obj.name))
```

This outputs the following data (in the print statement):

```
(0.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(10.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(20.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(30.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(40.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(100.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(0.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(10.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(20.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(30.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(40.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(100.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(0.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(10.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(20.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(30.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(40.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(100.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(0.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(10.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(20.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(30.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(40.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(100.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(0.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(10.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(20.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(30.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(40.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(100.0, Vector((-2.7375922203063965, 1.0250422954559326, 0.0)))
(0.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(10.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(20.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(30.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(40.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(100.0, Vector((-2.364258289337158, 0.9919000864028931, 0.0)))
(0.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(10.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(20.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(30.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(40.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(100.0, Vector((-2.0551865100860596, 4.03302001953125, 0.0)))
(0.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(10.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(20.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(30.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(40.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
(100.0, Vector((-1.7511816024780273, 4.02277135848999, 0.0)))
```

No animations has taken place!
Does anyone know how to make this work correctly?
The Bezier curves are animated in the 3D view when I change the keyframe with frame_set

Comment: The main problem seems to be that the curve positions and handles are not updated when changing the animation frame, even though they are updated 3D view

Comment: How are you animating the curve?

Comment: I create a couple of animation shapes in the curves panel. Then I made keyframes with them by pressing "I" over they animation key

Comment: To clarify: I created a Bezier curve, then modified it with some shape keys. I then created keyframes with these shape keys.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the shape keys aren't changing the original data. (they are non-distructive which is intentional).

But in this case you want the curve after deformation.

You can get the curve as a mesh, however this will have the bezier splines bakes into vertices.

*Posting this as an answer since nobody else stepped in, but Ill have to check if the API has some way to accessed the deformed curve.*

Comment: I found a way to access the shape keys, but that is a hacky solution. Why are shape keys intentionally non-destructive?